# Flutter / Dart: http.get returns no response

Tags: flutter, dart, http, https

I'm trying to retrieve data from two APIs one from my local Laravel application and another website.

The first request is successful but the second returns nothing, not even a status code.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class StreamAPI {
  Future<Data> getEmbedData() async {
    final videoHorizonResponse = await http.get(
      Uri.http('0.0.0.0', '/api/movie/634649'),
    );

    if (videoHorizonResponse.statusCode != 200) {
      throw Exception('Failed to load title data');
    }

    // prints 200
    print(videoHorizonResponse.statusCode);

    final superEmbedResponse = await http.get(
      Uri.https(
        'seapi.link',
        '/',
        {'type': 'tmdb', 'id': '634649', 'max_results': '1'},
      ),
    );

    // prints nothing
    print(superEmbedResponse.statusCode);

    if (superEmbedResponse.statusCode != 200) {
      throw Exception('Failed to load servers');
    }

    return Data.fromJson(
      jsonDecode(videoHorizonResponse.body)['title_data'],
      jsonDecode(superEmbedResponse.body)['results'],
    );
  }
}
```

Also when i try retrieving the data in my future builder it returns an error of null.

I'm not sure if i structured the data incorrectly.

```
class Data {
  final TitleData titleData;
  final StreamsList servers;

  const Data({
    required this.titleData,
    required this.servers,
  });

  factory Data.fromJson(
    Map<String, dynamic> parsedTitleJson,
    List<dynamic> parsedServerJson,
  ) {
    return Data(
      titleData: TitleData.fromJson(parsedTitleJson),
      servers: StreamsList.fromJson(parsedServerJson),
    );
  }
}

class TitleData {
  final String name, type, tagline, description, poster, backdrop;

  const TitleData({
    required this.name,
    required this.type,
    required this.tagline,
    required this.description,
    required this.poster,
    required this.backdrop,
  });

  factory TitleData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return TitleData(
      name: json['name'],
      type: json['type'],
      tagline: json['tagline'],
      description: json['description'],
      poster: json['poster'],
      backdrop: json['backdrop'],
    );
  }
}

// ? creates a list of stream objects
class StreamsList {
  final List<Stream> streams;

  StreamsList({
    required this.streams,
  });

  factory StreamsList.fromJson(List<dynamic> parsedJson) {
    List<Stream> streams = <Stream>[];
    streams = parsedJson.map((i) => Stream.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return StreamsList(streams: streams);
  }
}

// ? creates a stream object
class Stream {
  final String server, title, quality, url;

  Stream({
    required this.server,
    required this.title,
    required this.quality,
    required this.url,
  });

  factory Stream.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Stream(
      server: json['server'],
      title: json['title'],
      quality: json['quality'],
      url: json['json'],
    );
  }
}
```

Or if I'm accessing it incorrectly.

```
class _TitleOverlayState extends State<TitleOverlay> {
  late Future<Data> futureData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureData = StreamAPI().getEmbedData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Data>(
      future: futureData,
      builder: (context, title) {
        if (title.hasData) {
          return Stack(
            children: [
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Builder(builder: (context) {
                  if (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >
                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) {
                    return Image.network(
                      title.data!.titleData.backdrop,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Image.network(
                      title.data!.titleData.poster,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    );
                  }
                }),
              ),
```

Or perhaps it's because of the null response from the second request.

The entire data set returns a null error.

```
else if (title.hasError) {
          return Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Material(
              elevation: 5,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
              color: kSecondaryColor,
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Text(
                  // displays null text on the screen
                  '${title.data}',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
```

I can't seem to wrap my little coder brain around it, please help.
Thank you.

When refactoring to test the data from the fist response it works just fine.

Comment: If you get data from API refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71192690/13997210) hope its helpful to you.

Comment: The first answer helped in shorting my code by a few lines. I didn't think about directly calling the resource function in the future attribute. Thanks.